# Using F# Interactive in emacs?

Tags: emacs, f#, fsi

Ok, so I just got the F# extension working for emacs.  I now need to figure out how to make the scripts I write actually execute.  In Visual Studio, to run them you just highlight, right click, and choose "Send to Interactive".  I do not expect that emacs has that or anything similar, but I have no idea how to make an f# script interact with with fsi.  So, in essence, how do you run a script after writing it, using emacs or terminal?

EDIT: For clarification, I am running emacs on a mac.

EDIT2: Because I am running on a mac, emacs has no way to execute the script, since fsi doesn't exist as a usable thing for macs. Apparently. How sad. I will just choose the most voted answer as correct.

Comment: I think the key bindings (at least the Ctrl key bindings) are the same on a Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an Emacs user myself, but Laurent Le Brun has done some work on [F# mode for Emacs](http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2010/06/25/58-new-fsharp-mode-for-emacs), which is probably the most comfortable way to use F# from Emacs. His blog post talks about Alt+Enter, so I suppose the F# mode adds handling for this keyboard shortcut.

If you don't want to install this, then I guess you'll just need to run `fsi.exe` as a normal console application in another buffer and copy your F# intput there (appending `;;` to the end, to send the command to `fsi.exe`).

Answer (score 5):

According to [this page](http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2010/06/25/58-new-fsharp-mode-for-emacs) the readme file included with the package should document the keystrokes available. And, according to that readme, these are the keystrokes in question:

```
3) Bindings

If you are new to Emacs, you might want to use the menu (call
menu-bar-mode if you don't see it). However, it's usually faster to learn
a few useful bindings:

- C-c C-r       Evaluate region
- C-c C-e       Evaluate current toplevel phrase
- C-M-x         Evaluate current toplevel phrase
- C-M-h         Mark current toplevel phrase
- C-c C-s       Show interactive buffer
- C-c C-c       Compile with fsc
- C-c x         Run the executable
- C-c C-a       Open alternate file (.fsi or .fs)
- C-c l         Shift region to left
- C-c r         Shift region to right
- C-c <up>      Move cursor to the beginning of the block
```

So I'm guessing you want the Ctrl-c Ctrl-r combo.